# Is it possible to make columns in Bootstrap 3 all the same height without custom css?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Each column holds different content. such as a tags, text with different font size, and an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the content of the column varies, it's *not* possible w/o custom CSS in Bootstrap 3. IMO, [flexbox is the best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892773/171456) for same height columns in 3.x.

The Bootstrap 4 grid uses flexbox so same height columns are automatic.